# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

This is what I am currently running in the PyCharm Project

```
Windows 10
PyCharm 2020.1.1 (Community Edition)
Python 3.7.7
TensorFlow 2.2.0
```

This is what I have in codes in terms of imports:

```
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

Here are the errors......

> ```
> H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\compat\__init__.py:7:
> FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in
> the public API at pandas.testing instead.   from pandas.util.testing
> import assert_frame_equal Using TensorFlow backend. Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 58, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 28, in <module>
>     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 24, in swig_import_helper
>     _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
> "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py",
> line 242, in load_module
>     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py",
> line 342, in load_dynamic
>     return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "H:/Python/AI/LSMT.py", line
> 7, in <module>
>     from keras.models import Sequential   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in
> <module>
>     from . import utils   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6,
> in <module>
>     from . import conv_utils   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line
> 9, in <module>
>     from .. import backend as K   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line
> 1, in <module>
>     from .load_backend import epsilon   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py",
> line 90, in <module>
>     from .tensorflow_backend import *   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
> line 5, in <module>
>     import tensorflow as tf   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41,
> in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util   File
> "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py",
> line 50, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 69, in <module>
>     raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 58, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 28, in <module>
>     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "H:\Python\AI\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 24, in swig_import_helper
>     _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
> "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py",
> line 242, in load_module
>     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py",
> line 342, in load_dynamic
>     return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
> above this error message when asking for help.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

I have to tried uninstall, re-install, upgrade, change from Python 3.8 to 3.7, ..., but I still get an error.

Answer (score 0):

It was the version issue.

I changed TensorFlow to 1.15, cudart64_100 error showed up.

I then installed CUDA 10.1 with cudart64_101.dll problem still exist.

Then I followed this post....

https://www.joe0.com/2019/10/19/how-resolve-tensorflow-2-0-error-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64_100-dll-dlerror-cudart64_100-dll-not-found/

Downloaded, extracted the cudart64_100.dll provided by the OP....

Reinstalled TensorFlow 2.0.0.
Restarted my computer.
Problem Solved.

Only with the Future Warning; but no big deal. I can now run my program.

```
\pandas_datareader\compat\__init__.py:7: FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
Using TensorFlow backend.
```